# How to handle ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Rails properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I am trying to enforce uniqueness with unique index in my Rails project. And I found something confusing.

Like registering a user at my site, you need to provide an email address and a nickname, both need to be unique. I add unique index to both email and nickname. And when duplications come, I rescue exception `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`, now here's the question, how could I know which field cause the exception?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you should also add [uniqueness validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) to your model. That allows you to use Rails' validations and error messages.

```
# add to model
validates :email,    uniqueness: true
validates :nickname, uniqueness: true
```

Note that to ensure uniqueness on a database level a unique index is still needed.

Comment: Thanks @spickerman. Yes, I have validators for uniqueness. But still since I have multiple unicorn workers over multiple servers and also there's concurrency situations we need to deal with. We still need unique index to ensure data consistency.

That's what actually I am asking, if there's two field protected by the unique index, how could I know which one is triggering it.

Comment: I understand. In that situation just rescue from `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` and call `valid?` on the record again. That would populate the `errors` on the record with the information you are looking for.

Comment: OK, Thanks. Yes I am now using `valid?`. I am just posting this question to see if there's anything better, since `valid?` will run everything again.

Comment: Downvoting for this reason - Something to know about uniqueness validations.  Under the hood this is executing a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <TABLE> WHERE <table.value> == <record.value>` and it raises an exception if the value is > 0.  This may be fine, but can come back to bite you especially WRT to things such as bulk imports.  

IMO, uniqueness validations are one of rails sharp knives that should probably be avoided unless absolutely necessary.  A valid database foreign key with a uniqueness constraint is many terms more performant and doesn't introduce the race condition issues mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveRecord, you can use the [`valid?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#valid-questionmark-and-invalid-questionmark) method to run validations on your object. If it returns `false`, then you can view the error messages to determine which field(s) raised an error.

Example:

```rb
user = User.new(email: 'unique_email@google.com', nickname: 'non_unique_nickname')

user.valid? #This will run validations
# => false

user.errors.messages
# => {:nickname=>["has already been taken"]}
```

Comment: Yes, I am actually doing the exactly the same. But since `valid?` will run everything again, I am posting this question to see if there's anything better.